# Where could I find the oops info from kernel logs

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

I am a newer of driver development. I have configured my linux kernel according to the *Linux Device Driver* chaper 4, enabled a lot of debug configuration. When I try to test a driver written by me, the kernel issues an oops. This oops, however, immediately flushed by chunks of other debug information. So, where could I find out the oops info which occurred in a flash.

By the way, can anyone explain the meaning of debug information below?

```
[ 1698.129712] evbug: Event. Dev: input0, Type: 0, Code: 0, Value: 0
```

This type of message flushed by screen and I even can't stop them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid a lot of useless information (in your case) you have to enable only and only what you really need to debug your module. I highly recommend to disable everything you enabled back. Then case-by-case you may enable debug features.

Next, there is a nice framework in kernel called [Dynamic Debug](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt). It allows at runtime enable or disable certain debug messages (be sure you have `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_DEBUG=y` in the Linux kernel configuration). More detailed description is available in [Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/dynamic-debug-howto.txt).

`evbug` is a module to monitor input events in the kernel. There is one of the message it can issue. It's very simple one you may check at drivers/input/evbug.c. Unfortunately, it uses `printk()` calls directly and you can't manipulate its output through dynamic debug.

At the end the answer to your topic question is check output of `dmesg` command. But be aware that the kernel buffer for output is small enough and if you have a lot of logs you may miss some of them.

Comment: Your answer helps me a lot. I find that the `evbug` is compiled as module not in the kernel, so I can unload it manually from my system if I won't use it.